# Scroll UITableViewCell visible and highlight it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, ios9

I currently have the following setup: `UITableView` which leads (when the user selects a cell) to a `UIPageViewController`, so the user can scroll those same items presented in `UITableView` without constantly going back to and selecting another item.

When the user does go back, I want to scroll to the last viewed item in the `UIPageViewController` and highlight it, so the user knows better where (s)he is.

Using `tableView:scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` I can scroll to the last viewed cell, and with `tableView:selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` and `tableView:deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated`, I can highlight the cell. But I haven't figured out a nice, clean way to do both at the same time, that is, first scroll and then highlight the cell.

Here is my current working, but hacky solution, that could break down:

```
if let visible = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
    if !visible.contains(indexPath) {
        // cell is not visible, scroll required
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
        // highlight the cell after 0.4 seconds (aka somewhat after the scroll animation)
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.4 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)
            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    } else {
        // no need to scroll, just highlight
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Is there any nicer way of doing this, without relying on hard-coded timing?

Comment: I have similar desire in something I'm working on so if I figure out a more elegant solution I'll share. Mine is more for missing required fields if user tries something they're not supposed to, but same concept.

Comment: Where are you calling from this method tableView:scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated..?